# What causes the fail of windows system call StartServiceCtrlDispatcher failed with 1063 error (failed service controller connect)?

Tags: c++, winapi

I got problems with using WinAPI because I want to run an own service from my code. This problem is not common and I do not think that problem in source code of a service.
I've installed service with `CreateService` successfully. That's fine and it really appeared in register and services. So, I want running the service so I created entry point for service with using this table:

```
    BOOL ConsoleService::Run(ConsoleService &service)
{
    service_ = &service;

    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY serviceTable[] =
    {
        {service.name_, ServiceMain},
        {nullptr, nullptr}
    };

    return StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(serviceTable);
}

void WINAPI ConsoleService::ServiceMain(DWORD argc, PSTR *argv)
{
    assert(service_ != nullptr);

    service_->statusHandle_ = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(service_->name_, ServiceCtrlHandler);
    if (service_->statusHandle_ == nullptr)
        throw GetLastError();

    service_->Start(argc, argv);
}
```

But `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` failed with error 1063 (service controller connect). What can cause this problem?

Comment: [`ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-startservicectrldispatchera) what is unclear here ? you start program not via `StartService`

Comment: So I shoule use StartSevice instead? and how a controller relates to my service?

Comment: @AyratArifullin the SCM handles starting services. Your service's job is to respond to SCM requests. In this case, `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` is failing because your app is not being started as a service, so DON'T call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` at all. The documentation says: "*ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT: **This error is returned if the program is being run as a console application rather than as a service**. If the program will be run as a console application for debugging purposes, structure it such that service-specific code is not called when this error is returned.*"

Comment: @AyratArifullin do you call `CreateService()` from the same EXE as your service? IOW, is your service self-installing? If so, then you need to differentiate between when the EXE is run as an (un)installer and when it is run as a service.  When you call `CreateService()`, add a command-line parameter to the image path you use to run your service. And then make your EXE's `main()` look for that parameter to decide whether to call `ConsoleService::Run()` or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I used ```CreateService``` with the same image. Even I open services table and click on property on my service I can see that the pointed image is correct. Anyway I expect to install and run my service from executable file because as I understand that I can point to an image of my service during installation and also I want to start my service from executable file. Something like ```MyApp.exe start``` and in this way I know that my service was already installed but I should load entry point for it by ```StartService```

Comment: @AyratArifullin You can add another console application to start your service. Refer to "[Starting a Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/starting-a-service)" for how to do it.